# MongoDB find result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a connection table between users and messages and I will get all messageUserConnection - objects of sender (userCreatedMessage and userReceivedMessage are the same) and where message id is the same and read is `false` any messageUserConnection  or to say it simple: the sender/user will get all messageUserConnections sent where not all receiver have confirmed the message.

Query- string for MessageUserConnection:

```
db.MessageUserConnection.find()
```

`MessageUserConnection` entry for sender

a `MessageUserConnection` where the receiver of the message has not confirmed the message (messageId is the same and read = false)

```
{
  "confirmationNeeded": true,
  "read": false,
  "userCreatedMessage": DBRef("User",
  ObjectId("5589929b887dc1fdb501cdba")),
  "userReceivedMessage": DBRef("User",
  ObjectId("5589929b887dc1fdb501cdba")),
  "message": DBRef("Message",
  ObjectId("563c57adb1a9bb55d70bd407"))
}
```

Here is my Query:

```
db.MessageUserConnection.find( { $and: [ {'confirmationNeeded': true}, { $and: [ {'userCreatedMessage.$id' : ObjectId('5589929b887dc1fdb501cdba') }, {'userReceivedMessage.$id' : ObjectId('5689929b887dc1fdb501cdbc') } ] } ] } )
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to expand the query in order to consider the **read** property of the receiver.

It would be great if someone could give me a hint how I could do this.
Thanks a lot!

**[EDIT]**
[image: My Problem]

Here a graphic visualisation of my issue. What I will have is - in this case - only MessageUserConnection with id = 1 because one User (with id=3) which have received this message does not have read the message.
Is there any possibility to do this with one MongoDB query?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you want more then one condition in `$and` .. m i right??

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to query with $and the messageid of the sender and than how to check if **read** is set to false where messageid is the same like at sender- messageuserconnection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.MessageUserConnection.find( { $and: [ {'confirmationNeeded': true}, {'read': false}, {'userCreatedMessage.$id' : ObjectId('5589929b887dc1fdb501cdba') }, {'userReceivedMessage.$id' : ObjectId('5689929b887dc1fdb501cdbc') } ] } )
```

i think simply you can do this by upper mention query .. if i get your question.. don't know :(

Comment: Why even the first `$and`? MongoDB does $and between query elements by default